# Brand new Xamarin.Forms project: The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 and I'm trying to work on a Xamarin.Forms project. I cloned the existing repo and could build and deploy the iOS app just fine, but when I try to build the Android app it throws the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist. [Solution Name].Android C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets    1794
```

Everything works great in Xamarin Studio on Mac.

I created a clean Xamarin.Forms project in VS 2017 to isolate any particular solution issues and am getting the exact same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Error can be in drawable folder. Check if you image in drawable contain - or numbers and remove the symbols. drawable file must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Comment: @Tms852 I've seen other people mention that which is why I created a brand new solution like I said in the question. All that's in the drawable folder is the default app icon which has a legal name.

Answer (score 5):

This issue generally occurs when the correct Build Tools aren't correctly installed.

Open up the Android SDK Tools. Here is where it is if you are using Visual Studio.
[image]

Make sure you have the latest SDK Tools, Platform Toosl and Build Tools. Delete any preview or old build tools. I would use the Rev. 25 ones. Rev 24. had a few issues, I would make sure they are uninstalled.

Then make sure you have the correct SDK downloaded for whatever you are trying to compile for. E.g. 7.1, 7.0, 6.0 etc.

Then near the bottom I normally have at least

- Android Support Library Google
- USB Driver

After install, close all VS instances and start it up again.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is helpful. It fixes the problem with the new project, but the error persists in the old one even though I have everything installed. Any ideas there?

Comment: Are you targeting the same Compile, Min and Target API levels (SDK's) in the properties of your Android projects?

Comment: Yes, just checked.

Comment: Have you done a clean on the existing solution and rebuild? And maybe delete everything inside the Resources.Designer.cs file as well, just to be on the safe side. it will Auto regen the contents on it. Don't delete the actual file though, just whats inside of it.

Comment: I've done many many cleans/rebuilds and that hasn't done anything. I deleted everything in the Resources.Designer.cs in the Android project but I can't get the contents to regenerate.

Comment: First check that the Resources.Designer.cs is included in your project and set to Compile. Next I would unload the project that works and the one that doesn't and edit the csproj. Have a look at differences between the two to see if there is anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: @AdamPedley, your solution works like a charm... Revision 25 it's the more stable...